# If $U$ is an open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\bigtriangledown f(p)\neq0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

**If $U$ is an open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\bigtriangledown f(p)\neq0$ for all $p\in f^{-1}(c)$, then $S=f^{-1}(c)$ is a surface.**

My definition of surface is as follows: A surface is a presuperficie $X$ (related topological space such that for all $p\in X$, there exists an open environment $U$ of $p$ together with a homeomorphism $\phi:U\to \phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$) whose underlying topological space is Haudorff and second countable, equipped with a $A=\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ collection of neighborhoods in $X$ such that

$X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}$

and for all $\alpha, \beta\in\Lambda$ with $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}\neq\phi$, the transition functions:

$\phi_{\beta}\circ\phi_{\alpha}^{-1}:\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\to\phi_{\beta}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})$

$\phi_{\alpha}\circ\phi_{\beta}^{-1}:\phi_{\beta}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\to\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})$

they are applications $C^{\infty}$.

My question would be what would be the letters in this example, could it be $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}$? Why? And how do I show what follows? Thank you very much.

Comment: Surface is misleading. This is a smooth curve. Your definition needs to make it clear in what $\Bbb R^n$ the sets $\phi(U)$ are open subsets.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Not true. Is the domain of your $f$ supposed to be an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Then, as I said in my first comment months ago, $S$ will be a curve.